# REGEXP: Add a character before the first occurrence of a digit in a line

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a solution to add the symbol #  before the first occurrence of a digit in a line.

```
Input:
NewYork1986
Paris20
tokyo1

Expected ouput:
NewYork#1986
Paris#20
tokyo#1
```

So far, I've tried:

```
sed 's/\([0-9].\).*/#\1/g'

Which gives me:
NewYork#19
Paris#20
tokyo1
```

I guess I'm close but there's something missing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/#\1/g'` (or `sed 's/\([0-9]+\).*/#\1/g'` would be better if it works)

Comment: You are using `g` in your sed, this implies all occurrences. So all you need to do is: `sed 's/[0-9]/#&/'`. Find the first digit, and replace it with a `#` and whatever you matched `(&)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sed should work for you:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/#&/' file
```

```
NewYork#1986
Paris#20
tokyo#1
```

- You don't need to match for more than 1 digit without `g` (global) flag since all you need to do is to match first digit in every line.
- `&` is back-reference of full match by `sed` regex pattern.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: “[Boby Lapointe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boby_Lapointe)” is a famous french singer (died in 1972) all his songs are wordplay. Very difficult for a non native to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try with `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]/,"#&")} 1' Input_file
```

Though above is the simplest solution, in case you want to do it with reference method only then one could try following with GNU `awk`'s `gensub` function:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  re="([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)(.*)"
}
{
  print gensub(re,"\\1#\\2\\3","1",$0)
}
' Input_file
```